# How do I get the Firefox OS device id?

Tags: firefox-os

I want to store data on the server and keep it segmented for each phone.

How do I get a device's UID number?

Answer (score 2):

Per Mozilla's [Device Model Inclusion Requirements](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/User_Agent/Device_Model_Inclusion_Requirements), device makers and operators are **strongly discouraged** from adding a device identifier to the Firefox OS User Agent.

You should generate your own UID for each device that installs and runs your app, store it on your server and locally with either the Device Storage API (for privileged or certified app) or [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) (for un-privileged, un-certified app), and use your UID to segment and synchronize per-device data on your server.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [thread](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App/issues/14), there does not seem to be an API for getting the Device ID. I am not qualified enough to state if this still holds true.

Firefox OS also provides a list of Device Settings for privileged Apps but it looks like Device Id is not one of them. Take a look at this [Settings list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Platform/Settings_list).

Answer (score 1):

It's not meant to be used this way but you can use the window.location.host when your app is running to differentiate phones. The URL is a GUID that will be generated per app install, so it's different on different phones.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to be impossible to get UID of device with current API, you could create one yourself. Just generate unique value on the server, pass it to the client app and store it using [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage). Then use it each time you need this UID. This way you can also implement your own security policy for preventing "stealing" UID by other clients (you can control the length of the UID, change it from time to time etc).